# Class Library with third dependency c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I got a class library project who has a reference to a 3 party ddl it compile but when I include the library into another project it throw an exception because not found the third party library.

How can I solve this? I've be searching and found this [ilmerge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge) but I don't want to make a big dll with those library.

Note: I don't know if is relevant but the third party library also are include on the target project.

Answer (score 0):

If your library references a third party library then obviously you will need that third party library to be present.

You can either deploy the library in a folder on its own, merge it with another assembly (ILMerge will do that just fine as you found out), or just load it using the [AssemblyResolve event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: How can I deploy those reference on my own folder?

Comment: Did you take a look at the link ? The ResolveEventArgs object contains a **RequestingAssembly** property which you can replace in order to load the assembly from another location.